# Is there way to create a named set in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

We are looking at a modestly large graph (1M nodes). However when we look at the data, we can segregate it into smaller sets by using the attributes (e.g. language:ENGLISH). That part is easy enough. What we are looking for is a way to name that "set" (ENGLISHNODES) so for the rest of the operations ( and there are many) we don't have to specify the set other than the name, make it the default, and we can have some confidence that only the nodes with the attribute language:ENGLISH are being examined. I am hoping there is a simple way to do this that I just dont see.

We have about 100 cypher queries, so its just inelegant to include this as the opening statement in each one.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a label to these nodes, :EnglishNodes or similar, and once that label is set you can use that in your subsequent matches.

Comment: That was our only thought as well. Thank you. Confirmed what we expected. Thank you